# How to filter Dataset based on ENUM

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Could you please let me know how we can filter Dataset based on values in ENUM. Below is the sample dataset that I have created

```
case class Student(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, year: Long, dept: String)

val columns=Array("id", "firstName", "lastName", "year", "dept")
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "John", "Doe", 1986, "CSE"),
  (2, "Ive", "Fish", 1990, "CSE"),
  (4, "John", "Wayne", 1995, "ECE")
)).toDF(columns: _*)

val resDS = df.as[Student]
```

I have an existing ENUM which is used in different places. So want to use the same ENUM to filter dataset like below.

```
object DeptType extends Enumeration {
  type DeptType = Value
  val CSE, ECE, EEE = Value

  def contains(s: String) = values.exists(_.toString == s)
  def toList = values.map(_.toString).toList
}
```

Tried filtering dataset using the below 2 options.

```
resDS.filter(rec => DeptType.contains(rec.dept))
resDS.filter(rec => DeptType.toList.contains(rec.dept))
```

But both are failing with the below error. Could you please let me know how to filter using the ENUM.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2117)
  at scala.Enumeration.readResolve(Enumeration.scala:93)
  at scala.Enumeration$Val.readResolve(Enumeration.scala:259)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks good, I ran it on Spark 3 and Java 11.
One way I'd debug this is, I'd make sure that I have object `DeptType` outside `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit`  
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$` means the instantiated class for the Singleton object, in this case, `DeptType` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Enum values can be used in `isin` clause:

```
val enumStringValues = DeptType.values.map(_.toString).toList
val result = resDS.filter(col("dept").isin(enumStringValues: _*))
```